# Error when installing osgi jar in apache karaf

Tags: osgi

I have created an osgi bundle(which has jar file) using eclipse and placed in some other folder. 
    Then I copied that osgi jar file(from bundle) and plced it inside apache-karaf/deploy folder to deploy that jar. 
    And I started to run karaf. And I gave osgi:install D:\apache-karaf\deploy\osgiSample.jar in karaf@root.
But I got error like this...
"Unable to install bundle D:apache-karaf-2.3.2deployosgiSampleTest_1.0.0.201309201512.jar"

Pl help me out in solving this error.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The backslash "\" escapes the following character in the location. Use slashes "/" in the location as they are not escape characters or double backslash "\\".

Answer (score 0):

Putting the bunddle jar into the deploy folder will already install it. Just check with ls -al if the bundle loaded correctly. The answer about the backslash is also true of course :-)